# Get new position of item onClick after search via EditText in recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a `recyclerView`  and using `editText` to search the items in recyclerview. I've Click listener to get the position of whenever an item is clicked. It works perfectly fine when an item is clicked without searching. But whenever i search from edit text and click on some item it gives me incorrect position of the item.

Another issue is i've a function to close the fragment once the item is clicked from the recyclerview but somehow that function also doesn't work. :(

**Code for recyclerView**

```
    editText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.team_select_search);

    recyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.team_select_recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));

    list_items = new ArrayList<>();
    teamSelectAdapter = new TeamSelectAdapter(list_items, getContext());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(teamSelectAdapter);

    loadRecyclerViewData();

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

    teamSelectAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new TeamSelectAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            TeamSelectModelClass clickeditem = list_items.get(position);

            String team_id = clickeditem.getTeam_id();
            String team_name = clickeditem.getTeam_name();
            String team_logo_url = clickeditem.getTeam_logo_url();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(),team_name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            close_frag();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private void close_frag(){

        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).commit();

}

private void filter(String text){
    ArrayList<TeamSelectModelClass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TeamSelectModelClass item : list_items){
        if(item.getTeam_name().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }
    teamSelectAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
}
```

**Code for recyclerview Adapter:**

```
public class TeamSelectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeamSelectAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<TeamSelectModelClass> list_items;
private Context context;

private static ClickListener clickListener;

public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListener clickListener) {
    TeamSelectAdapter.clickListener = clickListener;
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<TeamSelectModelClass> filteredList){
    list_items = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public TeamSelectAdapter(List<TeamSelectModelClass> list_items, Context context) {
    this.context=context;
    this.list_items=list_items;

}

@NonNull
@Override
public TeamSelectAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.team_select_card_layout,viewGroup,false);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);



    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TeamSelectAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    TeamSelectModelClass teamSelectModelClass = list_items.get(i);

    viewHolder.textView_team_id.setText(teamSelectModelClass.getTeam_id());
    viewHolder.textView_team_name.setText(teamSelectModelClass.getTeam_name());
    if(teamSelectModelClass.getTeam_logo_url()!=null){
        Picasso.get().load(teamSelectModelClass.getTeam_logo_url()).into(viewHolder.imageView_team_logo);
    }else {
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.psa_logo).into(viewHolder.imageView_team_logo);
    }

}

public void clear(){
    list_items.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}



@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list_items.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout_team_select_card_layout;
    TextView textView_team_id;
    TextView textView_team_name;
    ImageView imageView_team_logo;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayout_team_select_card_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_select_card_layout);
        textView_team_id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_select_team_id);
        textView_team_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_select_team_name);
        imageView_team_logo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.team_select_team_logo);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        clickListener.onItemClick(getLayoutPosition(), v);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you try to use getAdapterPosition() instead of getLayoutPosition() in your ViewHolder class. Which you are overriding onClick method

Comment: @MuratGuc No change. It still gives an incorrect position. :(

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to send position but in my opinion just send your itemId like  `clickListener.onItemClick(list_items.get(getAdapterPosition).getTeamId(),  v);` and try to make process according to ID. not position. Because you are toasting items in your activity according to old list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void filter(String text){
    ArrayList<TeamSelectModelClass> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (TeamSelectModelClass item : list_items){
        if(item.getTeam_name().toLowerCase().contains(text.toLowerCase())){
            filteredList.add(item);
        }
    }
    teamSelectAdapter.filterList(filteredList);
    list_items.clear();
    list_items.addAll(filteredList);
}
```

Try this one in your activity. You are trying to toast items according to old **list_items** list.

Comment: Thanks man. This solved my issue. It was a silly mistake though. :)

Comment: No problem mate :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this........

try to get the Name of the item at the time of search and then check it from complete list like

```
Arraylist<String> names    //total names of items.
String serchItem           //name of item from search.
```

Then,....

```
if(names.contains(searchItem)){
    int position=names.indexOf(searchItem);
 }
```

if you find another way so please let me know......Thanks

Comment: Didn't get you :/